# How to dynamically change an image using javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, dynamic

So,i have this http://jsfiddle.net/ithril/UjGhE/1/
Please check it out.

What i'm trying here is to change the main image img tag's src dynamically to the same src attribute of the image that is clicked. In short whichever image is clicked,it is displayed in the bigger window which has an id="main-photo".

Comment: Check your "a" tag has href="" which reloads the page and img tag is a child of the "a" tag. My answer should make it work fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see my original code has made it this far :)
Because nobody has gotten accept, I will try my best. I will again give you some pointers on general matter:

1. Your hyperlink tags (`<a>`) are unclosed. This will surely generate a validation error. You can train your html skills be [validating yourself regularly](http://validator.w3.org/) (sounds dirty right?)
2. In `.main-photo img {}` the `position:relative:` is not closed with ;'
3. In your `.slider-large-image li img {}`, `margin: 10px` was not closed!

**NOTES**

- You could have added this question to your original one. I would have happily added this feature :)
- I again corrected your code a little.
- Is there a solid reason for using hyperlinks in your carousel list? I removed the  tags, since they made things unnecessarily complicated. You should do the same with the previous and next triggers.
- I'm not going to fix the layouting. You can figure it yourself out :)
- Miley rocks!
- I added default image, so when the page is loaded for the first time -- there wouldn't be a empty container.

**Live demo**

**http://jsfiddle.net/hobobne/K439d/**

**Full version code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title>How to dynamically change an image using javascript/jquery? - Kalle H. Väravas</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        html, body {margin: 0px; padding: 0px;}
                html, body, div, th, td, p, a {font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive; font-size: 12px; color: #000000;}
                .cb {clear: both;}
                #wrapper {width: 400px; margin: 0px auto;}
                    .main-photo{width: 80%; height: 400px; position: relative; border: 1px solid #000000;}
                        .main-photo img {width:100%; height:100%; position:relative; top: 0; left: 0px;}
                    .main-slider {float: left; position: relative; margin-bottom: 10px; border: 0px solid #000; top: 25px; left: 0px; -moz-border-radius: 5px; border-radius: 5px; -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px 1px #999; -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px 1px #999; box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px 1px #999; padding: 0px; color: #FFF; text-align: center; text-decoration: none; /*background-color: #CCC;*/}
                    .window {width: 700px; height: 230px; overflow: hidden; position: relative;}
                        .slider-large-image {position: relative; overflow: hidden; float: left; list-style-type: none; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;}
                            .slider-large-image li {margin: 0px; padding: 0px; float: left; display: inline-block;}
                                .slider-large-image li img {float: left; width: 200px; height: 150px; margin: 10px; cursor: pointer;}
                    .slider-pager {position: relative; z-index: 2; margin: -40px auto 0px;}
                        .slider-pager a {margin: 0px 2px; padding: 2px; text-align: center; text-decoration: none; font-size: 20px; font-weight: bold; color: #ccc;}
                            .slider-pager a:hover,
                            .slider-pager a:active {background-color: #999; -webkit-border-radius: 3px; -moz-border-radius: 3px; border-radius: 3px;}
                            .slider-pager a:hover {color: black;}
                            .slider-pager a.active {/* background-color and border-radius used to be here.. */}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div class="main-photo">
            <img id="mainphoto" src="http://www.insanemom.net/wp-content/uploads/miley-cyrus-smoking-bong.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="main-slider">
            <div class="window">
                <ul class="slider-large-image">
                    <li><img src="http://images.sneakhype.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/12/Miley-Cyrus-300x200.jpg" /></li>
                    <li><img src="http://wa2.www.3news.co.nz/Portals/0-Articles/185340/miley-cyrus_reuters_420.jpg?width=300" /></li>
                    <li><img src="http://cdn.buzznet.com/media/jjr/headlines/2009/03/miley-cyrus-ryan-seacrest.jpg" /></li>
                    <li><img src="http://images.smh.com.au/2010/12/29/2112265/miley_cyrus_400-300x200.jpg" /></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="slider-pager"><a href="#" id="b">&lsaquo;</a><a href="#" id="f">&rsaquo;</a></div>
        </div>
        <br class="cb" />
    </div>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var imagewidth = $('.slider-large-image li').outerWidth();
            var imagesum = $('.slider-large-image li img').size();
            var imagereelwidth = imagewidth * imagesum;
            $(".slider-large-image").css({'width' : imagereelwidth});
            $('.slider-large-image li:first').before($('.slider-large-image li:last'));
            $('.slider-large-image').css({'left' : '-' + imagewidth + 'px'});
            rotatef = function (imagewidth) {
                var left_indent = parseInt($('.slider-large-image').css('left')) - imagewidth;
                $('.slider-large-image:not(:animated)').animate({'left' : left_indent}, 500, function() {
                    $('.slider-large-image li:last').after($('.slider-large-image li:first'));
                    $('.slider-large-image').css({'left' : '-' + imagewidth + 'px'});
                });
            };
            rotateb = function (imagewidth) {
                var left_indent = parseInt($('.slider-large-image').css('left')) + imagewidth;       
                $('.slider-large-image:not(:animated)').animate({'left' : left_indent}, 500, function(){               
                    $('.slider-large-image li:first').before($('.slider-large-image li:last'));
                    $('.slider-large-image').css({'left' : '-' + imagewidth + 'px'});
                });
            };
            $(".slider-pager a#b").click(function () {
                rotateb(imagewidth);
                return false;
            });
            $(".slider-pager a#f").click(function () {
                rotatef(imagewidth);
                return false;
            });
            $(".slider-large-image li img").click(function() {
                $(".main-photo img").attr("src", $(this).attr('src'));
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's really simple to do this using jQuery. When the user clicks on an `<img>` tag, you'll have access to `this` inside the callback function. Simply take `$(this).attr('src')` and set the source of `$('#main-photo')` to it like so:

```
$('img').click(function(){
    $('#main-photo').attr('src', $(this).attr('src'));
});
```

-

It looks like in your code, you're using `.main-photo img`, which should also work. I'm looking at it more now.

-

EDIT, after reviewing your code, you seem to have many missing `</a>`s along with other errors. Here is an updated and working version (minus the CSS and extra javascript):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.slider-large-image a img').click(function() {
        $('img#mainphoto').attr('src, $(this).attr('src'));
    });
});
</script>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="main-photo"><img id="mainphoto" src="" /></div>
    <div class="main-slider">
        <div class="window">
            <ul class="slider-large-image">
                <li><a href=""><img src="http://images.sneakhype.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/12/Miley-Cyrus-300x200.jpg" /></a></li>
                <li><a href=""><img src="http://wa2.www.3news.co.nz/Portals/0-Articles/185340/miley-cyrus_reuters_420.jpg?width=300" /></a></li>
                <li><a href=""><img src="http://cdn.buzznet.com/media/jjr/headlines/2009/03/miley-cyrus-ryan-seacrest.jpg" /></a></li>
                <li><a href=""><img src="http://images.smh.com.au/2010/12/29/2112265/miley_cyrus_400-300x200.jpg" /></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="slider-pager"><a href="#" id="b">&lsaquo;</a><a href="#" id="f">&rsaquo;</a></div>
    </div>
    <br class="cb" />
</div>
```

Comment: Also consider using `"#"` inside the href tag on the links and adding `return false;` inside the callback.

Answer (score 1):

Change this part of your JS code:

```
$(".slider-large-image li a img").click(function() {

        $(".main-photo img").attr("src",$(this).attr('src'));

    });
```

to:

```
$(".slider-large-image li a").click(function() {        
   $(".main-photo img").attr("src",$(this).find("img").attr("src"));
   return false;
});
```

It should work fine. Eg: http://jsfiddle.net/UjGhE/23/

Answer (score 1):

```
$("ul.slider-large-image li a").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();      // prevent changing url
    $("#mainphoto").attr('src',$(this).children('a').attr('src')); //show clicked photo as main
});
```

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is remove the `href` attribute from your links. When clicked, this causes the page to reload. However, this attribute is also responsible for the cursor to turn into a pointer, so you'll have to manually assign one in CSS: `a { cursor: pointer }`

Clicking on the img's now would load said image in your main image holder, without the page reloading, which caused your problem.

I would clean up the html if i were you though, cause there are a lot of unclosed tags.