# Set background image dynamically for pages

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have one div#logo. i set background image for this div. I change image dynamically using jQuery.
and one common page which contain div#logo. i have one button from UI side which change the background image of div#logo.but when i redirect to another page div#logo page take default background image.

What i have to for all page which i select image form UI side button.

Comment: What server side scripting language you are using?

Comment: I think it will help you.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6973927/how-to-dynamically-change-an-image-using-javascript-jquery

Comment: You could store the current selection in a cookie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without persistent storage on the server side (and all the troubles arising from it like input validation etc.) I'd argue that you are best of storing the user's choice in a cookie.

Since you are using jQuery you could make use of the [jQuery Cookie plugin](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie).

```
$(function() {
    var img = $.cookie('background') || 'standard-bg.png';

    $('#logo').css({
        backgroundImage: img
    });

    $('button').click(function() {
       var img_src = $(this)... // However you determine the particular image

       $('#logo').css({
           backgroundImage: img_src
       });

       $.cookie('background', img_src);
    });
});
```

Comment: There is problem when i go back using browser Backward button.its load default image.

Comment: You need to show exactely what you've implemented. Otherwise it's impossible to tell what's the issue here.

Answer (score 0):

Store the background image url to `SESSION`.
And update this variable via `ajax` call on change of background image.

That way you will be able to get selected background image on all other pages.

EDIT:

**OR**

You can try javsacript session.

[Persist javascript variables across pages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1981673/persist-javascript-variables-across-pages)